# Python recursive determinant

Tags: python, recursion

I made a recursive function to compute the determinant of a matrix, based on the cofactors:

```
# determinant of a 2x2 matrix 
def det2(matrix):
    return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[1][0]*matrix[0][1]

# recursive part
def recursion(matrix,somme=None,prod=1):
    if(somme==None):
        somme=[]
    if(len(matrix)==1):
        somme.append(matrix[0][0])
    elif(len(matrix)==2):
        somme.append(det2(matrix)*prod)
    else:
        for index, elmt in enumerate(matrix[0]):
            transposee = [list(a) for a in zip(*matrix[1:])]
            transposee.remove(transposee[index])
            mineur = [list(a) for a in zip(*transposee)]
            somme = recursion(mineur,somme,prod*matrix[0][index]*(-1)**(index+2))
    return somme

def main(matrix):
    return sum(recursion(matrix))
```

Nothing complicated, except I don't understand why it doesn't work. It does give the right answer in some cases, but not all.
I suspect the result is wrong when there are 0s in the matrix, but I'm not sure.

If you have any idea,

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of an input matrix where the result is not correct, and include both the incorrect and the desired result?

Comment: [[4,6,3,5,1],[1,4,5,3,7],[6,5,1,5,6],[8,5,3,4,3],[6,0,7,0,7]] 
expected result: 1335
result: 4695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is probably here:

```
transposee.remove(transposee[index])
```

The `remove` removes the *first* occurence of the value passed to it from the `list`. Your test matrix has several duplicate values and so the one removed may not be the one you want removed to create your `mineur` array.

Your algorithm works for random arrays because such duplicates are unlikely to occur in this case.

To make your program work, replace the line with

```
del transposee[index]
```

which will remove specifically the value at `index`.